# Leveraging data from intent MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT

Tags: android, io, uri

I've been trying to get my Uri data to persist from a camera function but am having no luck.  I've used several examples on stackoverflow but still am not understanding what I am doing wrong.  the intent data in onActivityResult is null because the camera activity is destroying the MainActivity I am working in.  I tried to save this in SaveInstanceState but I am still getting null.  What am I missing?

here is the saveInstanceState:

```
    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state){

    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    if (mImageData != null) {
        state.putString("cameraImageUri", mImageData.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
        mImageData = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
    }
}
```

Here is the intent setup and file creator:

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

    log("in dispatchTakePictureIntent()");
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            log("Exception caught.  Aborting image creation" + ex);
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            mImageData = takePictureIntent.getData();  //Trying to save the data.
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    log("in onActivityResult()");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //Intent data is null right here.
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;

        try
        {
            mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SelfieObject selfie = new SelfieObject(mCurrentPhotoPath, photo);
        startNotification();

        //method call for ListViewAdapter.add
        //addNewPic(selfie);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    log("in createImageFile()");
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

public void addNewPic(SelfieObject selfie){

    log("in addNewPic()");

    mAdapter.add(selfie);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this still concerns you, but I'll give it a go.

It's unclear what you are trying to do. When you have a request to *pick* an image, the uri of the picked image will be available in the Intent data. When you have a request to *take* a photo with the camera, it's you who decides where it gets saved. It's this line in your code:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
```

So in this case, you'll always get null in your Intent data, as you don't need it: the photo is saved at whatever Uri photoFile holds.

You clearly do not need this line:

```
mImageData = takePictureIntent.getData();  //Trying to save the data
```

... and there's also no need to persist it in onSaveInstanceState.

I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I'll check this as accepted because others might need help for it too.  Thanks!